# C - comparison and cast char* to char

Tags: c, if-statement, casting, char

I have the following code:

```
char* line[255];
....
line[0] = '1'; // filled char by char
....

char charCode = (char)line[i];
if (charCode == '\t' || charCode == '\n' || charCode == ',' || charCode == ' ')
{
      // do someting
}
```

The IF condition I'm using to find space, comma, tab, or end of line. The warning I get from GCC:

```
   warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

Can someone help me spot the issue here? Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
line[0] = "1"; // filled char by char
```

to this:

```
line[0] = '1';
```

Also, change:

```
char* line[255];
```

to:

```
char line[255];
```

In C, string literals in double quotes `"` are of type `char *`, while literals enclosed in single quotes `'` are character literals with type `char`. Also, you have declared an array of pointers to characters (or an array of strings, essentially) where I think you just wanted an array that can hold 255 characters.

Comment: This is wrong while `char *line[256];` is the declaration.  The assignment to `line[0]` is correct; the reference to the first character should be `line[i][0]` and not the blunderbuss cast which converts a pointer to a `char` and provokes the warning which means pretty much exactly what it says (there are essentially no machines where `sizeof(char *) == sizeof(char)`).

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. I should have looked more carefully at the declaration! I think OP must be confused, I picked up on the "// filled char by char" part.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed the question to '1'. In my code, it is single quotes.

Comment: Thanks - your answer helped me figure a few things out. :)

Comment: @JeremyWest: The answer is almost certainly wrong. I very much doubt the OP meant array of 255 pointers to char. Much more likely should have been `char line[255]`.

Comment: @david I'm confused... that's what I suggested he change it to, in which case this answer is correct.

Comment: @JeremyWest: Sorry, I missed the edit. The first 5 lines of your answer have been made wrong by his edit. This is very confusing, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's too hard to do this in comments. The code should look like this.

```
char line[255];
....
line[0] = '1'; // filled char by char
....

char charCode = line[i];
if (charCode == '\t' || charCode == '\n' || charCode == ',' || charCode == ' ')
{
      // do someting
}
```

The array should be char, not char*. That fixes the error. Then the cast is not needed.